# Scala map a Vector of tuples to vector of object

Tags: scala, slick

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.language.implicitConversions
import scala.concurrent.{Future, Await}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object test extends App {  
  case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

  implicit def t2p(t: (String, Int)) : Person = Person(t._1, t._2)

  val f:Future[Vector[(String, Int)]] = Future {
    Vector(("One", 1), ("Two", 2))
  }

  val s = f.mapTo[Vector[Person]]

  Await.result(s.map { _ foreach { x => println(x)}}, 5.seconds)
}
```

I am trying to convert a Vector of tuples to a Vector[Person] but the above code result in a casting exception even though there is an implicit tuple to Person conversion function?

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.Tuple2 cannot be cast to example.test$Person
    at example.test$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(test.scala:19)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at example.test$$anonfun$2.apply(test.scala:19)
    at example.test$$anonfun$2.apply(test.scala:19)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mapTo` just attempts a cast, so of course trying to cast `Vector[(String, Int)]` to `Vector[Person]` is going to fail.

You need a function that will convert `(String, Int)` to `Person`, and that function is the tupled version of the `Person.apply`.

Thus, replace

```
f.mapTo[Vector[Person]]
```

with

```
f.map(_.map(Person.tupled))
```

Comment: I replaced `f.mapTo[Vector[Person]]` with `val s = f.map(x => x.map(y => Person(y._1, y._2, y._3)))` but yours is better, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use directly:

```
  val f:Future[Vector[Person]] = Future {
    Vector(("One", 1), ("Two", 2))
  }
```

You can see this answer for more info about using `mapTo` with `Future`s: [Using mapTo with futures in Akka/Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314093/using-mapto-with-futures-in-akka-scala)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the signature of `mapTo`:

```
def mapTo[S](implicit tag: ClassTag[S]): Future[S]
```

It doesn't take an arbitrary conversion function. Remove your `t2p` and the code will still compile and fail in the same way. `mapTo` actually performs a Java-style cast, which is why it needs the `ClassTag`.

Instead you could do this:

```
val s = f.map(vec => vec.map(Person.tupled))
```